# Como puedo visualizar una imagen en vue js si la imagen esta guardada en la carpeta del back?

Tags: nodejs, vue.js, express, multer

```html
<v-card-text>
  <v-row>
    <v-img :v-if="im != undefined" v-for="(image, i) in im" :key="i" :src="'../../../API/uploads/'+im[i]" width="100">
      <v-btn
        fab
        text
        color="indigo lighten-1" 
        @click="DeleteImage(i)"
      >X</v-btn>
    </v-img>
  </v-row>
</v-card-text>
```

y me da el siguiente error

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot GET /API/uploads/pexels-frank-cone-2258536.jpg</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Entonces la única manera que me muestra las imágenes es si estas guardadas en la carpeta public de Vue JS pero Multer no me deja guardar las imágenes fuera de la carpeta del proyecto